# Does WCF automatically URL encode/decode streams?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, url-encoding

I'm programming a service for a program that uses HTTP post/get requests, so I handle all incoming requests with a hook method that takes a `System.IO.Stream` and returns a `System.IO.Stream`.

When I parse the incoming request (contained in an HTML form) by converting to a string and then using `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string)`, it seems to automatically URL-decode the data. When I return a file path (a Windows UNC, not going to explain why I do *that*), I initially URL-encoded the string before converting to a stream and returning it using a return-statement, the client seems to get a doubly-coded string.

So, just to be sure, does WCF automatically URL encode/decode streams for me as part of using `System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it does:

"For RESTful services, WCF provides a binding named System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding.
This binding includes pieces that know how to read and write information using the HTTP and HTTPS transports, as well as encode messages suitable for use with HTTP."

from [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780321612366/ch08lev1sec3).